# Add note on reschedule ONLY for one reschedule

Tags: org-mode

I can add:

```
#+STARTUP: lognotereschedule
```

and it will prompt me to insert a note every time I reschedule using `C-c C-s`.

But I want to enter a note only on one (or a few) reschedules.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add notes at will independently of TODO state changes and rescheduling.

`org-add-note` (bound to <kbd>C-c C-z</kbd> will prompt for a note to add to the current TODO item.

Similarly, in the agenda display, [typing <kbd>z</kbd>](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html#index-z) will call `org-agenda-add-note`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(defun org-schedule-force-note ()
  "Call org-schedule but make sure it prompts for re-scheduling note."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-log-reschedule "note"))
    (call-interactively 'org-schedule)))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-S-s") 'org-schedule-force-note)

(defun org-deadline-force-note ()
  "Call org-deadline but make sure it prompts for re-deadlining note."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-log-redeadline "note"))
    (call-interactively 'org-deadline)))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-S-d") 'org-deadline-force-note)
```

So whenever I want to take a note on why I re-scheduled something or moved a deadline, I use `C-c C-S` or `C-c C-D` instead of `C-c C-s` or `C-c C-d`.

---

**EDIT 2019-12-31**:

As it is somewhat related to this: I recently wanted to force note taking on re-scheduling for a certain important headline even if I were to forget using the corresponding command. According to the documentation on `org-log-reschedule` this should be possible by setting the `LOGGING` property of this headline to `note`. However, this does not work for me. Will check back if I ever get it to work.